# Most common color in bitmap(data)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to extract the most common color of a bitmap. My first idea was to do this by looping through the bitmapData and extracting every pixel color and storing it in an array.

But the function has to be as light as possible so my question is; Is there a more lightweight approach to achieve this?

The function is used to extract background color of a Bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

The [histogram()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#histogram%28%29) function of the BitmapData class can be used for this. Check out http://cc.mcgarrybowen.com/labs/2011/02/tip-use-as3s-histogram-method-for-color-averaging/ for the info behind it

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to just guess that for example the top left pixel is part of the background and use that color?

Comment: good idea, it's not 100% certain but that is my own suggestion isn't either

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the sort of visual information presented some variation of [Monte Carlo method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) may fit. In particular, if you are displaying photographic images, then sampling randomly (where [random is weighted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence)) would give you fair enough representation. So, for example, you could choose to use [xor-shift random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) (as it would be faster then AS3 `Math.random()`) and read the color values from the ByteArray generated from BitmapData in a way: `pixels.readUnsignedInt(xorShiftRandom() * pixels.length)` in case BitmapData uses ARGB format.

Also, you would want to build a histogram so that similar colors would create a majority. You would then have to take some arbitrary choice as to what extent colors are considered similar (how many bins of a histogram count towards the same color) and thus find the most common color by trying groups of bins.

You could also preprocess the image (by downsampling it). I don't have any mathematical proof off-hand, but it feels like you wouldn't need an image larger then 255x255 to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You could downscale the bitmap, give it a big blur and then pick the colour in the middlepoint.