# AS3 - Find the most abundant pixel colour in BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, bitmapdata, argb

Basically, I want to get the most common ARGB value that appears in a `BitmapData`. That is, I want to know which *exact* pixel colour is the most abundant in the image. I tried going through every pixel of the image and counting whenever a colour that already exists comes up, but that's way too slow, even with relatively small images. Does anybody know a faster method for this, maybe using the `BitmapData.histogram()` function or something?

Ideally the process should be near instantaneous for images around at least 1000x1000 pixels.

Comment: I found a similar question with a good answer, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9879812/1123633

Comment: I've seen that: unfortunately the solution appears to find the average colour, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the single colour value that appears the most times in an image. Like if you have 20 pixels that are `0xFF89ae00`, and 10 that are `0xFFae0089`, the resultant colour I would get would be `0xFF89ae00`, because that's the colour that most pixels have.

Comment: Oh okay i misunderstood the answer (to the one i linked), sorry ^^.

Comment: Are you using [getPixel()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel()) or [getVector()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getVector())?

Comment: I was using `getPixel32()`: now I see that `getVector()` is better for this use, but I hadn't used it before Vesper's answer.

Comment: I think that this could be usefull for you: http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/extract-average-colours-from-bitmapdata

Comment: Sorry, that's the same as Johan's suggestion: it gives the average, not the most common.

Answer (score 1):

Run through `bitmapData.getVector()` with a Dictionary to hold numbers, then sort that Dictionary's key-value pairs by value and get the key of maximum.

```
var v:Vector.<uint>=yourBitmapData.getVector(yourBitmapData.rect);
var d:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
for (var i:int=v.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
    if (d[v[i]]) d[v[i]]++; else d[v[i]]=1;
}
var maxkey:String=v[0].toString();
var maxval:int=0;
for (var k:String in d) {
    if (d[k]>maxval) {
        maxval=d[k];
        maxkey=k;
    }
}
return parseInt(maxkey); // or just maxkey
```

Comment: Thanks, that works greatly (I'm not sure why you're iterating through the `Vector` backwards though, works fine for me forwards). Unfortunately it's still slower than I need it to be (although it is comparatively fast). I'll leave this unanswered to see if someone knows of something quicker, if that's even possible. If there aren't any answers for the next day or two I'll accept this one.

Comment: I expect nothing is faster, as you need to query every single pixel and make an exact color histogram, this requires complete iteration. Why backwards - we don't need to maintain order to count, but if we go forwards, we constantly check vector length, it isn't as fast as checking against zero.

Comment: Ah, good point, never thought of that. I'll be sure to remember that in the future for when order doesn't matter. Most likely you're right, this is probably the fastest method with this level of accuracy, but may as well see if something magical comes up.

Comment: @puggsoy It's just as easy to save the length in a local variable. I do this very often: `var lng:uint = myArray.length; for(var i:uint = 0; i < lng; i++) {... }`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with shaders at all, but I think you might be able to get faster results. Looping through pixels is faster at the shader level.

I'd try by creating essentially the same loop in the shader, and paint the entire resulting bitmap with the most used colour and sample that (unless you can get a variable directly out of the shader)

this should be significantly faster

Comment: I'll give this a go. I've never worked with `Shader`s before though and they don't look like your average class so I'll have to look into it.

Comment: isnt it that shader in flash doesnt support loops?