# AS3 BitmapData Percentage Comparison

Tags: actionscript-3, compare, percentage, bitmapdata, erase

I'm working on a game with a lawn mower that orients itself to the mouse and colours white over a grass Bitmap to give the illusion of a mower cutting (erasing) grass.

I want to create a function that checks the percentage of grass cut, which basically means checking how much white is currently drawn into the grass image.

How would I go about doing this? Is there an easy way?

Here is my current code:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.Event;

var bitmapData = new grass();

var bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

var mower = new Mower();

var radiance:Number = 180/Math.PI;

var erase:Sprite=new Sprite();
erase.cacheAsBitmap = true;

bitmap.y=0;
bitmap.x=0;
addChild(bitmap);

addChild(erase);

addChild(mower);

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void
                  {  
                        erase.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
                               erase.graphics.drawCircle(mower.x,mower.y,25);
                        erase.graphics.endFill();

                        var mowerdirection = -    (Math.atan2(mouseX-mower.x, mouseY-mower.y))*radiance;
                        mower.rotation = mowerdirection;

                        followMower();

                        var myTestingBitmapData:BitmapData =     new BitmapData(bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height, true, 0x00000000);

                        trace( myTestingBitmapData.compare( bitmap.bitmapData) )

                  });

erase.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event):void
                    {
                        trace('click');

                    });

function followMower():void 
 {
var dx:int = mower.x - mouseX;
var dy:int = mower.y - mouseY;
mower.x -= dx / 10;
mower.y -= dy /10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use image analysing frameworks or some methods to count colour in an image. There is build in function called [histogram](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#histogram%28%29) that may help you, you can also use solution of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388164/as3-find-the-most-abundant-pixel-colour-in-bitmapdata) or under [this link](http://cc.mcgarrybowen.com/labs/2011/02/tip-use-as3s-histogram-method-for-color-averaging/)